# Código com entradas indeterminadas, mostrando os pares em ordem crescente e ímpares em ordem decrescente

Tags: java, loop

Estou fazendo um exercício onde o usuário coloca uma quantidade indeterminada de números e eles tem que ser apresentados dividindo os pares dos ímpares, sendo os pares de forma crescente e os ímpares decrescente.

A minha dúvida é como aproveitar o loop do meu código para no fim apresentar todos. Poderia fazer usando classes como `ArrayList`, mas gostaria de saber se tem uma forma de continuar no meu código.

```
package exer5proposto2;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Exer5Proposto2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n1 = 0, maior = 0, menor = 100000, cont = 0, i;
        String aux = "", resp = "";

        while(!"n".equals(resp)){
            aux = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Informe um número ");
            n1 = Integer.parseInt(aux);
            cont = cont+1;

            if(n1 % 2 == 0){
            for(i = 0; i < cont; i++){ //esse for poderia estar fora do while, no entanto ele ia guardar apenas uma posição (sendo impossivel fazer comparação), 
                if(maior < n1){      //então para não ter que fazer um vetor coloquei o for dentro do while assim ele ja faz as comparaçoes e salva 
                    maior = n1;  //essa seria uma das importancias de um vetor, armazenar um valor de um loop para outro loop externo a ele
                }            
            }
            }else{
            for(i = 0; i < cont; i++){ //esse for poderia estar fora do while, no entanto ele ia guardar apenas uma posição (sendo impossivel fazer comparação), 
                if(menor > n1){      //então para não ter que fazer um vetor coloquei o for dentro do while assim ele ja faz as comparaçoes e salva 
                    menor = n1;  //essa seria uma das importancias de um vetor, armazenar um valor de um loop para outro loop externo a ele
                }            
            }
            }
           resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Informe 's' para continuar e 'n' para sair");

        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu código não armazena todos os números lidos. Logo, não há como ele pode exibi-los depois em qualquer ordem que seja.

Ou seja, você provavelmente vai ter que:

- Usar duas `ArrayList`s, uma para os pares e outra para os ímpares. Você pode usar isso:

  ```
  (n % 2 == 0 ? pares : impares).add(n);
  ```
- Após ler todos os números, ordenar os `ArrayList`s usando o [método `sort(Comparator)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-).
- Utilizar como parâmetros ao método `sort`:

  - `(a, b) -> a - b` - ordem crescente.
  - `(a, b) -> b - a` - ordem decrescente.